# when set the value by jquery in angularjs, angular showing required validation of that field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using Jquery datepicker in AngularJS.

My date field is required, when I select the  date and then want to submit the form, even the value is there, but AngularJs showing error.

```
My Code:
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Date" class="form-control" id="txtDate" name="txtDate" ng-model="myCtrl.txtDate"  ng-required="currentStep == 1" close-text="Close" ng-click="startOpen($event)"  />
                                                <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="frmAddBid.txtDate.$dirty && frmAddBid.txtDate.$invalid">Date is required</span>

And DAtePicker is shwoing by:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#txtDate').datetimepicker({});

});
</script>
```

Thanks,

Comment: can you manually set `.$dirty` and manually clear `.$invalid` from the input in a callback on the picker?

Comment: try to trigger `input` event in selection callback. Should also put that code into a directive

Comment: Thanks for reply dandavis! But I don't want validate manually. Can you please provide me some example. Thanks Much!